# How to randomly permutate data in SQL (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, permutation

What is the best way to randomly permutate data?
Example:

```
id col1    col2     col3
1  data11  data12   data13
2  data21  data22   data23
3  data31  data32   data33
```

I want randomly permutate data in col1 and col2, result will be like this:

```
id col1    col2     col3
1  data31  data22   data13
2  data11  data12   data23
3  data21  data32   data33
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use DBMS_RANDOM to acheive randomness.  The ROW_NUMBER() in the sub-queries provides a hook which you can use in a WHERE clause, otherwise you'll get a CROSS JOIN (which isn't very random and may well be huge).

```
with c1 as ( select col1
                , row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value ) rn
             from your_table )
     , c2 as ( select col2 
                , row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value ) rn
             from your_table )
     , c3 as ( select col3 
                , row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value ) rn
             from your_table )
select c1.col1
       , c2.col2
       , c3.col3
from c1, c2, c3
where c2.rn = c1.rn
and   c3.rn = c1.rn;
```

For best results remember to use a seed.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#sthref4646).